# Freezes - iOS app with Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash, freeze

Sometimes one of my app freezes, out of nowhere (apparently).
I have to kill the app to restart it. 
It happens 1/50 times and it does not happen when I do something specific.
I really have a hard time recreating the issue for debugging.

Does someone have this kind of issue? If no, what would you advise for debugging purposes?

I'm on *iPad Air 2 with iOS 10.3*.

I dev it in **Unity 5.5.0**

Have a good one,

Comment: It's impossible to help you or determine what's going on without your code. Problems like this are usually caused by improper use of the `while` loop, constantly creating coroutines every frame, instantiating and destroying objects.

Comment: I know it is, I can't myself. That's the reason why I'm asking for debugging advises. Thank you for your answer thought, that's a start, but I'm usually avoiding this kind of "errors" during the dev. I'll double check my whiles
Thank you.